# Flow Simulation for Laminar Flow in Annular Gap?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow, simulation, ansys

Would anyone be able to run an air flow simulation through the following geometry at 100 cc/min? I'm curious if any dead spots occur and if the geometry of the annular gap will produce laminar flow.

[image: e]

Dimensions are in inches.

Reynold's number analysis:

Hydraulic Diameter* = 0.003 in = 7.62E-5 m
Absolute Viscosity of Air at 20.2C = 1.983E-5 N-s/m^2
Density of Air at 20C = 1.293 kg/m^3
Mean Velocity = 
   => A_cs = 0.004089 cm^2
   => Q = 100 cc/min
   => V = 24455.9 cm/min = 4.076 m/s

Therefore,

Re = (rho*V*D)/nu
   = (1.293 kg/m^3 * 4.076 m/s * 7.62E-5 m) / 1.983E-5 N-s/m^2
Re = 20.25

Comment: Have you thought about calculating to see if you will get laminar flow?

Comment: I have and am getting some odd Reynold's numbers. Based on the above geometry and flow rate of 100 cc/min, how would you calculate the Reynold's number?

Comment: Show your analysis for the Reynolds number...

Comment: I edited the post to reflect my Reynolds number analysis. I think I may be having a fundamental issue with what the cross-sectional area of an annular gap is and/or what to use for the hydraulic diameter.

Comment: @SolarMike Any ideas?